# How could random functions be really random?

Tags: function, language-agnostic, random

**Introduction**

I know I'm going to lose a lot of reputation for this question and I also know it will be flagged as inappropriate but I'm really curious about that so I'm not giving up if there's any chance I'm getting at least an answer.

**Question**

Today I woke up thinking:

> Hei, how could random functions be really random if they are created by an algorithm?

Think about it. How could you create a function that simulates randomness without the concept of random already built in? I began to think:

> Hei, I'd take an array of int, then I'd do [thing], then [thing], than [thing] again, then I'd choose only odd numbers... ecc

But it seems more likely a function that make it more confusing to predict what the choose will be rather than real randomness.

Is it possible to create randomness? How are functions that returns random ints (such as `rand()` in PHP) created? How can they simulate randomness?

Comment: The truth: they can't. You can't create *true* randomness mathematically. You can, however, generate * pseudo* randomness. And in 99% of cases, that's good enough. I'm *sure* questions about this have been asked/answered here before; do a search if you're concerned about losing a bunch of rep to drive-by downvoters.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how does random() actually work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359318/how-does-random-actually-work)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Functions that algorithmically produce so-called random numbers are [**pseudorandom number generators**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator). If you know the *seed* used to generate the sequence, then the numbers are *predictable*. The sequence itself is a *statistically random* distribution but not truly random.

There *are* **true** random number generators that typically involve some hardware that samples randomness from the physical world, e.g., radioactivity or acoustic noise. A naive implementation would be to sample hard disk access and mouse movements. See [random.org](http://www.random.org) for a real RNG.

Obligatory [*xkcd* strip](http://xkcd.com/221/):

[image: getRandomNumber()...]

Comment: A non-radioactive hardware implementation http://www.youtube.com/v/7n8LNxGbZbs&hl

Comment: @belisarius It's a real life Rube Goldberg machine!

Answer (score 1):

There's a reason they're called *pseudorandom* numbers; they're not truly random. [From Wikipedia:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator)

> A pseudorandom number generator
>   (PRNG), also known as a deterministic
>   random bit generator (DRBG),`[1]` is an
>   algorithm for generating a sequence of
>   numbers that approximates the
>   properties of random numbers. The
>   sequence is not truly random in that
>   it is completely determined by a
>   relatively small set of initial
>   values, called the PRNG's state.

Answer (score 1):

Read [volume 2, chapter 3 of this seminal work](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Art_of_Computer_Programming) if you want the maths behind it.  You can [buy it](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201485419) to look impressive on your bookshelf.  (Just keep in mind that most people who buy it wind up never actually reading it -- for a good reason.  It's VERY dense and VERY difficult reading.)  The short answer that doesn't involve massive tomes of difficult text is that "random" numbers generated purely algorithmically are [pseudorandom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandomness), which is to say that they are "random enough".

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into wikipedia's article on [PRNGS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator) - what all random number generators we have on PCs (pretty much) are.

About the closest you can get to random, which I think is done somewhere, is to use temperatures in the CPU or some other sensor reading as a seed for one of these. If the seed is random (the temperature is unlikely to ever be exactly the same), the sequence is about as close to random as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I usually "get Milliseconds" and divide it to a pseudorandom number. This makes it even more random and unpredictable.