# Which is more random: human- or software-generated number?

Tags: language-agnostic, random

> Does it **toss a coin** to get random bit?
>   Or **throw a die** to get a random integer from 1 to 6?
>   Or **take a card from a  shuffled deck** to get a number from 1 to 52?
>   .
>   .
>   .
>   Or can it think like us or have intelligence like us?

Obviously the above examples can't be ways of generating random data.

Then how do software libraries generate `random` numbers on a given range?
**Which is more random: human- or software-generated?**

Comment: Wikipedia actually has some decent quality articles on the subject, like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator (in particular look at the Linear Congruential Generator)

Comment: http://xkcd.com/221/ Sorry, I couldn't resist :-/

Comment: spraff: It gets old by now, honestly.

Answer (score 11):

*(Note: This is generally about random [and pseudo-random] numbers in computing and their uses.)*

You can never have true random numbers with a deterministic process, which is why computers are fairly ill-suited to generate them (as the CPU can only flip bits in a deterministic manner). Most languages, frameworks and libraries use so-called [*Pseudo*-random number generators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PRNG) (PRNG). Those take a *seed* which is sort of an initial state vector which can be a single number or an array of numbers and generate a sequence of seemingly-random values from there. The results usually satisfy certain statistical measures, but are not totally random, as the same seed will yield the exact same sequence.

One of the easiest PRNGs is the so-called [Linear Congruential Generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) (LCG). It just has a single number as state (which is initially the seed). Then for each successive return value the formula loops like this:

[image: LCG formula: x_(n+1)=a⋅x_n+b (mod⁡c )]

where *a*, *b* and *c* are constants for the generator. *c* is usually a power of two, such as 2<sup>32</sup> simply because it's easy to implement (done automatically) and fast. Finding good values for *a* and *b* is hard, however. As a most trivial example, when using *a* = 2 and *b* = 0, you can see that the resulting values can never be odd. This limits the range of values the generator can yield quite severely. Generally, LCGs are a very old concept and long supplanted by much better generators, so don't use them, except in extremely limited environments (although even embedded systems can handle better generators without problem, usually) – [MT19937](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_twister) or its generalization, the [WELL generators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well_Equidistributed_Long-period_Linear) are usually much better for people who simply don't want to worry about the properties of their pseudo-random numbers.

One major application of PRNGs is simulation. Since PRNGs can give an estimate or guarantee of statistical properties *and* an experiment can be repeated exactly due to the nature of the seed they do quite well here. Imagine you're publishing a paper and want other people to replicate your results. With a hardware RNG (se below) you have no other option than including every single random number you used. For Monte-Carlo simulations which can easily use a few billion numbers or more this is ... not quite feasible.

Then there are random number generators for cryptographic applications, e.g. for securing your SSL connection. Examples here are Windows' [CryptGenRandom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CryptGenRandom) or Unix's [`/dev/urandom`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dev/random). Those often are *also* a PRNG, however they use a so-called “entropy pool” for seeding which contains unpredictable values. The main point here is to generate unpredictable sequences, even though the same seed will still yield the same sequence. To minimize the effect of an attacker guessing the sequence they need to be re-seeded regularly. The entropy pool is gathered from various points in the system: events, such as input, network activity, etc. Sometimes it's initialized also with memory locations throughout the system assumed to contain garbage. However if it's done, care must be taken to ensure that the entropy pool really contains unpredictable stuff. [Something that Debian got wrong in OpenSSL a few years ago.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_number_generator_attack#Prominent_examples_of_random_number_generator_security_issues)

You can also use the entropy pool directly to get random numbers, (e.g. Linux's [`/dev/random`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dev/random); FreeBSD instead uses the same algorithm for `/dev/random` as for `/dev/urandom`), but you don't get too much out of it and once it's empty it takes a while to replenish. That's why the algorithms mentioned above are usually used to extend what little entropy there is to larger volumes.

Then there are hardware-based random number generators, which use unpredictable natural processes, such as radioactive decay or electrical noise in a wire. Those are for the most demanding of applications requiring many “truly” random numbers and are able to generate a few hundred MiB of randomness per second, usually (ok, that data point is a few years old, but I doubt it can be done much faster by now).

You can emulate such things by writing a program taking images from a webcam with lens cap on (only noise remains, then) or from audio input when no actual input is present. Those are fine for a little hacking, but usually will not generate *good* random numbers, as they are biased, i.e. in the bit stream zeroes and ones are not represented with the same frequency (or, going further, the sequences `00`, `01`, `10` and `11` are not generated with the same frequency ... you can do this for larger sequences as well). So a part of an actual hardware RNG goes into making sure that the resulting values satisfy certain statistical distribution properties.

Some people [actually throw dice to get random dice rolls](http://www.gamesbyemail.com/dicegenerator) or even [take this into overdrive](http://gamesbyemail.com/News/DiceOMatic). And humans make [very bad random number generators](https://scienceblogs.com/cognitivedaily/2007/02/05/is-17-the-most-random-number).

Comment: There are a number of webservices that provide real random numbers. For example, random.org uses the static that occurs in 3 untuned radios as a source of entropy for generating random numbers

Comment: The claim of something "Debian got wrong" is rather mis-stated. OpenSSL was using uninitialized memory as entropy, which both invoked undefined behavior, and could have failed to get any entropy if the uninitialized memory happened to read all-zeros (or any other predictable pattern). Debian fixed half of the bug, but failed to provide a new, actually-valid entropy source.

Answer (score 3):

A compiler does absolutely nothing with regards to requiring a random number. A compiler merely makes your code, call some other code which returns a random number. Now the "other code" which calls the random number might be:

1. Implemented within your code.
2. Implemented as a part of a standard library.
3. Implemented as a part of a special library.

In cases (1) and (2), it is mostly a pseudo-random algorithm, and the numbers you get aren't really random. If it is part of a standard library (like cmath or math.h), then one cannot say for sure that the result values are pseudo-random because the standards specify only the definition and not implementation.

EDIT: The library is stdlib.h and it is ALWAYS a psuedo-random number as pointed out by Joey and phresnel. Read comments for details on their answers. I apologize for the error and I agree that I should have known better than to reply on instinct.

Special libraries may be used which may have special implementation of other algorithms, like the Mersenne Twister algorithm. Also, they may be nothing more than drivers of Hardware that can generate random numbers. Hardware random number generators return somewhat "true" random numbers http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_random_number_generator.

Random number algorithms from standard libraries eventually map to system calls on the OS. So, on linux, for example, you may simply be reading from `/dev/random` or `/dev/urandom` (or you may be doing the same thing in your own code as well).

Also note that, true randomness can be achieved without using dedicated hardware or some dedicated service. `/dev/random` and `/dev/urandom` provide random numbers, which for all intents and purposes can be considered true.

EDIT: Some special libraries or your own code may even be using a network service for random numbers (many of which provide true random numbers).

Comment: Your post sounds a bit like you just copied from the other posts ... Also it is pretty wrong right in the first paragraph: `man 3 rand` explitly says `pseudo random number generator`. Also, how can you implement `srand()` for true random numbers? Apart from that, `rand()` and `std::rand()` are in `stdlib.h` and `cstdlib`, and **not** in `cmath/math.h`

Comment: @phresnel: Different architectures have different implementations. If a device running a dedicated Hardware RNG chooses to implement rand that way, why can it not? And I did not say "true random number generator", I said, "for all intents and purposes, can be considered true". And the mention of the wrong library file was a mistake

Comment: C guarantees a behavior for `rand()` and `srand()`, namely that the sequences generated by `rand()` are always repeatable by calling `srand()` with the same value. A hardware RNG cannot satisfy those, thus `rand()` must always be a PRNG. It doesn't need to be the braindeadly broken LCG published in the standards decades ago, admittedly and can vary between implementations.

Comment: @Rohan Prabhu: You wrote `If it is part of [e.g. cmath], then one cannot say for sure that the result values are pseudo-random because the standards specify only the definition and not implementation.` **This is absolutely wrong, actually it is a lie.** _The standard **explicitly** writes_: `The rand function returns a __pseudo-random integer__.`

Comment: @Joey, @phresnel: In that case, I'm extremely sorry for saying so. It is an honest mistake from my side, because I assumed it to be so.

Comment: @Rohan P.: The section "Random number algorithms from standard libraries eventually ..." is misleading, too

Answer (score 2):

Those numbers generated by your computer are not "random" by the true definition of "random". They are pseudorandom - there is an algorithm that generates numbers. Here you can read more about those numbers: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator

Comment: True random is possible, and by design supported on some operating systems. Also, there is not "an algorithm that generates numbers", but many.

Answer (score 2):

Google random number generation:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_number_generation

Whist not truly random I would choose a computer to generate a random number any day
humans are rubbish at randomness as they behave in a predicitable way

see:
http://www.physorg.com/news186174216.html

Answer (score 1):

See Joeys answer. There also exist *[hardware random generators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_random_number_generator)* which use some physical process to produce nouse and which can be plugged into your computer to be used for "true" random number generation (in the mathematical sense, the "true" is superfluous").

Under Unix-likes, such devices could be queried at /dev/random and /dev/urandom.

For an online example, see http://www.random.org/ .

Also make sure to have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki//dev/random.

Answer (score 0):

This is linux-specific but there is some OS support for "real" randomness: `/dev/random` and `/dev/urandom`. You read these like normal files.

`random` is real randomness gleaned from physical processes such as irregular latencies in the hardware -- it is depleted when you read it and is cryptographically secure.

`urandom` is a limitless pseudorandom source which is derived from `random` and almost certainly higher quality than your C library PRNG.

Comment: That's not real randomness unless /dev/random / /dev/random are plugged into a "true random device". The OS can't be non-deterministic without some help. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki//dev/random .

Comment: /dev/random *is* plugged into a "true random device" (the motherboard), it doesn't HAVE to be a *dedicated* true random device. The only consequence is that /dev/random generates entropy more slowly without a dedicated random device. It's still *really* random. If your OS has a bad implementation then that's another matter.

Comment: That's interesting news to me. Mea culpa. I'd remove the -1, but it seems locked, sorry.

Comment: To my knowledge it is only truly random if you include outside sources in your entropy, such as network packets sent to you. If a computer is completely self-contained and gets no outside input, then you're back to the beginning.

Comment: Joey, hard disk seek time is a local example. Yes you can write malicious code that will make the seek time somewhat regular, but if you measure it in nanoseconds, take the lowest few bits and hash then mechanical effects dominate any application logic.

Comment: On a modern machine, measuring just about anything in nanoseconds will give you at least a few bits of real entropy.

Comment: Not neccessarily, the clock might only be accurate to microseconds. This is why you should take more than just the last bits and hash them -- that way it doesn't matter whether the entropy is in the last bit or the 5th.

Answer (score -3):

Surely human is more random. Compiler (actually, the random module which is compiled by the compiler) only uses some dummy-random (not actually random, just likely) algorithm to generate a random number.

Comment: It's ok to vote down for my answer but I would like to know why?

Comment: No, human generated random numbers are bad: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_number_generator_attack#Human_generation_of_random_quantities

Comment: I'm not one of the down-voters, but it's a poor quality answer with little substance - see some of the other responses for examples of how the question could be better answered.

Comment: One of the why's is already there. Re-iterating: Humans generally produce noise of lesser quality than PRNGs or even Hardware-RNGs do.

Comment: Just because I think the asker may find deep explanation somewhere else on the Internet (Google it). It would lead to some deep articles concerning randomize. I think StackOverFlow just need to supply the idea and in some rare case when the asker really need more detail, then we will.

Comment: @phresnel:In means, human created such a precious thing which can think beyond the human thinking.

Comment: About human generated random numbers: please think about a person can think of any number instantly, really RANDOM. But when it takes to a series of number then human may be not as good as computer.

Comment: But every human has preferences. If my boss would ask for a random number, I'd probably answer 7 because I like it.

Comment: Humans are lousy at randomness, particularly when they try their hardest. http://faculty.rhodes.edu/wetzel/random/intro.html gives a good feel for just how bad you are.

Comment: What if your boss ask you for a BIG random number? I think you would answer 10312312312 or some think like that!

Comment: @longbkit: See @msw 's link. To show you what I mean, could you maybe generate 10 numbers between 0 and 10 and I'll try to prove it is a bad sequence?

Comment: just as a sidenote: I would answer 32768, because I like 2^n.

Comment: I once wrote down 100 "random" hex digits. The computer told me there was only about 40 bytes (80 digits) of entropy in them.

Comment: You guys did not get my idea. My idea is that if thinking about ONE random number, human is very good, but if need a series of random numbers then it's a hard job

Comment: @longbkit: Please use "@name" so we get notified and you won't wonder why noone replies anymore.

Comment: @longbkit: Even if that was true, which it is not (see my remarks on my favourites: I will always prefer 2^n and for some reasons prime numbers (personal fav. "7") as well as numbers of the golden ratio (1,2,3,5,8,13,...)), it wouldn't change much. If you are asked one time, then you are already biased for the next time someone requests a single number by you.  Also, even if you generate just one number in your whole life, what could you do with that single number? Imho, that's irrelevant.

Comment: Seven is the un-random number as it is my first choice too.