# How does a computer produce randomity?

Tags: random

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how does random() actually work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359318/how-does-random-actually-work)

My art teacher used to always tell us how computational randomity is never *truly* random. As a determinist I don't think that randomity exists at all, but my programming-related question is this:

**How exactly does a computer produce a "random" number?**

Comment: [Obligatory obvious link you've probably already seen but was bound to be posted anyway](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator)

Comment: Also worth mentioning http://www.random.org/

Comment: Your art teacher is not quite correct. You can create truly random numbers by using an entropy source (an element having content partly depending on randomness like a high-precision timer) and bit-mixing algorithms (e.g. secure hash algorithms) to generate such numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Random numbers produced by computers are typically *pseudo* random. See: [pseudorandom number generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator).

Basically there is an algorithm that produces a sequence of values deterministically. These values are spread across the range so they look like random, but they are completely predictable. Typically you start generator with some *seed* and if you use the same seed, generator will produce the exact same output every time.

## See also

- http://www.random.org/ - truly random number based on atmospheric noise
- http://www.entropykey.co.uk/ - hardware USB device based on analog noise in transistors

Comment: So, I'd have a function, that does some math on a number, such as (simplified): `function foo($seed) { return $seed * 42; }`, and the programming language would remember the lastly used seed and use a new one on next occasion, e.g. the old one increased by one?

Comment: @MarttiLaine Yes, exactly (except it returns only a part of the seed and doesn't just multiply to get the next seed). Picking a good sequence is tricky.

Comment: @MarttiLaine: pretty much. Have a look at [standard Java implementation](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/util/Random.java#Random.next(int))